# Are tabular and multidimensional models built the same way?

Tags: ssas, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular, multidimensional-cube

I'm having a real hard time understanding what the difference is between a tabular vs multidimensional model.

Don't both use dimensions and fact tables?

Can't both have a star or snowflake schema?

Don't both have measures and calculated columns?

What is the difference?

Also, if I'm using Power BI and I connect to SQL Server instead of SSAS, I can still do my thing with it. Why is SSAS needed for tabular models if you can just do it in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Don't both use dimensions and fact tables?

Nope.  Multidimensional uses Attribute Hierarchies and Measure Groups.  Tabular uses Tables, and has no built-in notion of what a "fact" or "dimension" is.

> Can't both have a star or snowflake schema?

Yes.  And Tabular can have other designs as well.  Tabular models can have single-table, or more normalized schemas, although using a star or snowflake design is generally considered a best-practice.

> Don't both have measures and calculated columns?

MD does not have calculated columns.  See [Comparing tabular and multidimensional solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/comparing-tabular-and-multidimensional-solutions-ssas)

> Also, if I'm using Power BI and I connect to SQL Server instead of SSAS, I can still do my thing with it.

Nope.  Power BI *always* uses a Tabular or Multi-Dimensional model.  When you connect to SQL Server with Power BI you are creating a Tabular model, and either Importing the data into memory, or creating a DirectQuery model (or a hybrid).  In either case there is still a Tabular Model created, either embedded in the .PBIX or in a SSAS/AAS server.